# Encoding in PHP curl post/put

Tags: php, json, curl, character-encoding

I'm trying to send JSON via curl in PHP to a REST web service.
It works fine when I am using English letters, but I'm getting errors for some international characters.

For some characters, such as Ð, ð and ó, I don't get an error, but when I look at the final product (I'm transmitting data to another database), the letters have been replaced by question marks. Só "`Óli`" becomes "`?li`"

For other characters, such as Þ, I get a 500 error from the web service: "No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page"

When I try to use iconv, utf8_encode, utf8_decode or mb_convert_encoding and then use curl, I get the same error as with Þ.

In case, you are wondering, the other database does allow international characters (I am able to type them directly into the database and/or upload with CSV).

I've tried adding
    `curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );` and `curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8" );` to the curl.

I've tried adding `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` to the php file (not sure if this has any impact on curl or if it only impacts how it displays in the browser).

```
$json = '
{ 
"CardUniqueId": "1",
"PersonName": "Þæö"
}';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $uri . $action);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('api-key: '. $apikey));
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" ); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Is there anything I am forgetting?

Note: I think I have done this before using the same curl settings, without problems, but it's been a while, so I might be mistaken. But I mention that because there is a chance the owner of the web service has made some changes on their end, causing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting that JSON is a data transfer format, and not just a string. Use appropriate tools when working with it:

```
$data = ["CardUniqueId" => 1, "PersonName" => "Þæö"];
$json = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: That's what I did initially. I changed it to a string just because I was worried that json_encode was causing those errors.

Comment: Wait, I must have changed something since then. I tried using json_encode again, and this time more characters are working when I don't do any charset encoding. But when I add iconv or utf8_encode, there seems to be a problem with json_encode. No json is created.

Comment: I'm still having troubles with the charset encoding, but I'm going to mark this one as the correct answer, as it is getting me in the right direction. I'm still missing some characters though.

Comment: JSON is perfectly capable of handling full Unicode, PHP just escapes it out of an abundance of caution. It's entirely possible the problems you're seeing are on the server side.

Comment: Currently, I am trying to figure out why I'm getting this error: "Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string" when I do this: iconv("Windows-1252", "UTF-8", $PersonName); I've tried every charset that I can think of. I always either get this error or json_encode gives no result.